# Ayuda para hacer una pregunta sobre cómo Instanciar un método como parámetro de una clase desde otra

Tags: soporte, revisión-de-pregunta

Quisiera que me ayudaran a formular esta pregunta, pues no sé cómo hacerla y cuidar los detalles de la misma para que no sea botada como negativa en **SOes**.

El tema quizás podría ser: **Instanciar un método como parámetro de una clase desde otra**.

Tengo una clase destinada a manejar los eventos de los *JFrame* que tengo creados. Eso me permite jugar con ellos y no instanciar código en su estructura, cuestión de mantener una relación **Modelo, Vista, Controlador**. Dentro del **frame principal** tengo un **JTable** y quisiera que cada vez que se iniciara el *frame* ese *JTable* tomara la estructura de un **DefaultTableModel** creado dentro de la clase de los eventos. Por cierto, no sé si crear una clase solo de eventos y otra de funciones.

El código del de la clase manejadora de eventos es el siguiente:

```java
public class ControladorEstudiante{

    EstudianteAdmin estAdmin= new EstudianteAdmin();
    EstudianteDAOImpl estDAO= new EstudianteDAOImpl();

    public ControladorEstudiante(EstudianteAdmin estAdmin, MostrarEstudiante estMostrar){
        this.estDAO= estDAO;
        this.estAdmin= estAdmin;
    }

    public void initEstudiante(){

    }

    public void ListarTabla(JTable tabla){
        DefaultTableModel modeloTabla= new DefaultTableModel();
        tabla.setModel(modeloTabla);

        modeloTabla.addColumn("NOMBRE");
        modeloTabla.addColumn("MATRICULA");
        modeloTabla.addColumn("NOTA");

        Object[] columna= new Object[3];

        int objGuardados= estDAO.extraerTodos().size();

        for (int i = 0; i < objGuardados; i++) {
            columna[0]= estDAO.extraerTodos().get(i).getNombre();
            columna[1]= estDAO.extraerTodos().get(i).getMatricula();
            columna[2]= estDAO.extraerTodos().get(i).getNota();

            modeloTabla.addRow(columna);
         }
    }
}
```

El siguiente es el código del *frame*:

```java
package comm.estudiante.interfaz;

public class EstudianteAdmin extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public EstudianteAdmin() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        menuFunciones = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu();
        submenu_Modificar = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jSeparator1 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
        submenu_Eliminar = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jSeparator2 = new javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator();
        submenu_EliminarTodos = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        txtBuscar_estudiante = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnAgr_estudiante = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tablaEstudiante = new javax.swing.JTable();

        submenu_Modificar.setText("Modificar");
        menuFunciones.add(submenu_Modificar);
        menuFunciones.add(jSeparator1);

        submenu_Eliminar.setText("Eliminar");
        menuFunciones.add(submenu_Eliminar);
        menuFunciones.add(jSeparator2);

        submenu_EliminarTodos.setText("Eliminar todos");
        menuFunciones.add(submenu_EliminarTodos);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        btnAgr_estudiante.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/comm/estudiante/imagenes/Nuevo Contacto.jpg"))); // NOI18N
        btnAgr_estudiante.setText("Crear Estudiante");

        tablaEstudiante = new javax.swing.JTable(){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex,int columnIndex){
                return false;
            }
        };
        tablaEstudiante.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {

            },
            new String [] {

            }
        ));
        tablaEstudiante.setComponentPopupMenu(menuFunciones);
        tablaEstudiante.setFocusable(false);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tablaEstudiante);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(txtBuscar_estudiante, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 229, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(btnAgr_estudiante, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 153, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txtBuscar_estudiante, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnAgr_estudiante))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 258, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EstudianteAdmin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EstudianteAdmin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EstudianteAdmin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(EstudianteAdmin.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new EstudianteAdmin().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAgr_estudiante;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JPopupMenu.Separator jSeparator2;
    private javax.swing.JPopupMenu menuFunciones;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem submenu_Eliminar;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem submenu_EliminarTodos;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem submenu_Modificar;
    private javax.swing.JTable tablaEstudiante;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtBuscar_estudiante;
    // End of variables declaration

    public javax.swing.JTextField getTxtBuscar_estudiante(){
        return txtBuscar_estudiante;
    }

    public javax.swing.JButton getBtnAgr_estudiante(){
        return btnAgr_estudiante;
    }

    public javax.swing.JTable getTablaEstudiante(){
        return tablaEstudiante;
    }

    public javax.swing.JMenuItem getSubmenu_Modificar(){
        return submenu_Modificar;
    }

    public javax.swing.JMenuItem getSubmenu_Eliminar(){
        return submenu_Eliminar;
    }

    public javax.swing.JMenuItem getSubmenu_EliminarTodos(){
        return submenu_EliminarTodos;
    }
}
```

Este es el código del método **extraerTodos()**:

```java
public List<Estudiante> extraerTodos() {
    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmnt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM notas";
    List<Estudiante> lista = new ArrayList<>(); 

    try {
        con = dbcon.conectar();
        stmnt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sql);

        while (rs.next()) {
            lista.add(new Estudiante(
                rs.getInt("id"),
                rs.getString("nombre"),
                rs.getString("matricula"),
                rs.getInt("nota")
            ));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lista;
}
```

¿Cómo hacer para pasar el método **ListarTabla** como **parámetro del método constructor** del *frame principal* siguiendo el patrón del **MVC** y evitando instanciar código en una **Vista**?, o ¿Como hacer para **iniciar el frame y que la tabla tome ese DefaultTableModel**?

Comment: Agrego referencia de la pregunta ya hecha: [Asignar un DefaultTableModel a un JTable (MVC)](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/23295)

Answer (score 2):

Creo que falta algo a tu planteamiento. La guía [*"Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable"*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) determina tres características que debe tener el código que compartimos (copio y pego):

- …Mínimo - usa el mas poco código posible que **reproduce el mismo problema**
- …Completo - asegurate de proveer todas las partes necesarias para **reproducir el problema**
- …Verificable - prueba el código que aportas para asegurarte que **reproduce el problema**

La clave de las tres características es que el código nos ayuda a reproducir el problema. Pero en el código que compartes no hay indicaciones que nos ayuden a reproducir el problema.

Más aún, si tu problema es que no tienes idea de cómo pasar un método como variable, el código no es relevante.

Un ejemplo sería:

> Al usar una instancia de una clase como parámetro de un constructor obtengo un error `ERR001 ¿En serio?`. Este es mi código:
>
> ```java
>     public void ListarTabla(JTable tabla){
>         // Lo que hace este método.
>     }
>
>     public int LaOtraClase(ListarTabla objeto) {
>         // Lo que se supone que hace esta clase.
>     }
>
>     // Se crea la instancia de la clase ListarTabla
>
>     // Se crea la instancia de la clase LaOtraClase que
>     // usa la instancia de arriba como parámetro
>     // y no pitufa
>     // ^^^^^^^^^^^
>     // ERR0001 ¿En serio?
> ```
>
> Y aquí ocurre el error.

Evidentemente de Java solo sé que no sé nada, pero, el problema, desde mi punto de vista es que creemos que para contestar debemos agregar algo de código, el que sea, pero no es así.

Incluso, en este caso, que quizás el problema sea de patrones de programación más que un caso específico, no sea necesario un ejemplo real y específico.

¿Cómo se crea una instancia en Java, con `miOtraClase = new LaOtraClase()`?

Comment: Tienes razón, no hay el código suficiente, gracias, veré como hago para proveer mas información